# Parse-Platform query with pointer to non-objectId field always returns null

Tags: pointers, join, parse-platform, one-to-many

I have two collections in Parse using mongoDB : access and tokens ;

access collection;

[image]

tokens collection ;

[image]

this is how I add records to access ;

```
//Enter Record into Parse with Block  
        ParseObject accessObject = new ParseObject("access");
        accessObject.put("tokenid", anaQrCode);
        accessObject.put("locationid", routeID);
        accessObject.put("pTokenId", ParseObject.createWithoutData("tokens", anaQrCode));
        accessObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e != null){
                    //error in save
                } else {
                    //save success
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

this is how I query to get data from both collections in single query ;

```
 //get query result from database
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("access");
        query.include("pTokenId");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    //error
                    Log.d("TAG1", "error " + e);
                } else {
                    //success
                    for (int i=0; i< objects.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject tmpPtoken = objects.get(i).getParseObject("pTokenId");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The issue is, the tmpPtoken object is returning null all the time.

My goal is the retrieve below info in a single query ;

[image]

Comment: Your column name is 'p_pTokenId' in picture but you are setting 'pTokenId' when you save object in your code.

Comment: Thats right, Parse has a convention when naming pointer fields. Automatically '(underscore)_p_(underscore)' is added as prefix for pointer column names.

Comment: For more clarity after Suat's comment ; if I had created the pointer by referencing the objectId in tokens collection, I do not have an issue with the response to my query. However, to get the objectId from tokens collection, I must make one more query which defies my purpose to obtain the lookup field in a single query. Essentially, I need to join tables like we would have done in sql.

Comment: Can you please share your parse schema? Your data looks wrong. You should have tokens' _id in the _p_pTokenId and not tokens' tokenId

Comment: Davi, you are right indeed. I deliberately use tokenId in _p_pTokenId because at the time I am saving the record in access, I don't have means to know the _id from tokens collection; without an additional query. Because I know the tokenId at the time of saving the access record, I wanted to use tokenId as pointer parameter for the lookup collection(tokens). Unfortunately the query is returning null in this case and I would like to understand why